# MongoDB query by compound indexed values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Given a collection of rows like

```
------------------------
date    | time | value
------------------------
20190101| 0930 | 0.00
20190101| 0931 | 1.23
20190102| 0930 | 9.83
20190103| 0745 | NaN
....
------------------------
```

an I created a compound index (e.g. (date, time)) on the collection. What is the fastest way to query for records whose (date, time) are in the list -- for example,

```
query items that match:
{date:20190101, time:0931} or {date:20190102, time:0930}
should return
------------------------
date    | time | value
------------------------
20190101| 0931 | 1.23
20190102| 0930 | 9.83
------------------------
```

There is a `$in` aggregation but idk how to use it on multiple fields. By the way I am using pymongo.

Comment: Something that is important in querying compound index is the order of fields in index should be match with your query. e.g. if in your index first field is date, you need to query based on that then by time. Could you please provide an example of what exactly you want to search? (finding documents between two specific dates?)

Comment: Thanks, @MohammadTaherian. I've updated the question for a more clear example. It seems that Ali got my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get an example of a query using $in:

```
db.collection.find({
    date: {
        $in: [date0, date1, date2]
    }
})
```

This same operation has the same result as a sequence of $or :

```
db.collection.find({
    $or: [{
        date: date0
    },
    {
        date: date1
    },
    {
        date: date2
    }]
})
```

With this in mind, is possible to have the same behavior as an $in statement with multiple fields by translating it to this $or notation:

```
db.collection.find({
    $or: [{
        date: date0,
        timestamp: time0
    },
    {
        date: date1,
        timestamp: time1
    },
    {
        date: date2,
        timestamp: time2
    }]
})
```